# Why does the internet connection lag when I hold the phone in a specific way?

Tags: hardware, internet

I want to know what's really at play between my smartphone, Android 11, and my holding has to do with loading content.

By "loading content", I mean when I enter a search term in Chrome, when I open YouTube, to Chrome loading the search results, to the search result I click on, going to the web page. Once on the web page, the content loading just trying, trying, trying to load.

It takes a noticeable time to complete the loading, which sometimes doesn't load at all until I sit the phone down like a table or anything really, out of my hands, off of my lap when I'm sitting, not touching the phone, and bam, the content loads almost immediately.

It's happened so much that I took notice of it, now I want to know what's really going on here.

Comment: Anecdotally, I have experienced a similar issue while holding the top part of the phone, and then the internet connection suddenly lagged. My assumption is that the hand somehow blocked the WiFi receptor enough that the signal got disrupted. However, this is just a wild guess since Physics-wise, I thought the WiFi signal should pass through the hand easily.

Comment: Not with Wi-Fi, but with Mobile Data I've been observing the same behavior on almost all phones I've used so far. So I conclude that cellular radiations are certainly weakened by the human body.

Answer (score 1):

Humanoids (that's you... and maybe even me) are made of materials that are fairly effective at blocking (absorbing) radio signals of many different wavelengths and frequencies.

To transmit and receive data via radio waves (such as by WiFi and mobile data), your phone uses at least one antenna.  When you place your grubby paws over an antenna, your extremities restrict - to a degree - effective transmission/receipt of radio waves.

When I get any new phone, I always determine where the antennas (and microphone(s)!) are located within the device so I don't accidentally block them with as I hold the device.

A *"pro tip"* I discovered years ago is to keep a short, but wide, round glass cup where you often use your phone.  When you need a better connection, place your phone in the empty glass cup.  This will keep your hands off the phone while providing a stand that may actually improve reception just a bit. This technique has worked well for me for quite a few years.

Answer (score 0):

Try turn off Experimental QUIC Protocol by navigating to [chrome://flags/#enable-quic](https://chrome://flags/#enable-quic) and disable it from the dropdown.

Comment: Could you explain why this setting is relevant to the issue, which seems related to physical instead of software?

Comment: Google Chrome uses QUIC to connect to all google services by default. As such all requests to google services via the Google Chrome browser use UDP instead of TCP.  On the surface, QUIC is very similar to TCP+TLS+HTTP/2 implemented on UDP. Because TCP is implemented in operating system kernels, and middle box firmware, making significant changes to TCP is next to impossible. However, since QUIC is built on top of UDP, it suffers from no such limitations. Because QUIC protocol is based on top of UDP, packet delivery is not 100% guaranteed. Chrome have this QUIC protocol turned on by default!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, that's certainly helpful, but still... for this specific question, what I (and possibly the OP) want to know is why was there a connection issue when the phone was held and no issue when it was not touched?

Comment: Wow, I knew someone would know what's going on from Stackexchange. Thank you all very much